# How to terminate a Docker container which is running as part of bash script when the bash script is killed?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

```
#/bin/bash 
docker run ubuntu sleep 3000
```

I have a bash script which runs docker container but when the script is terminated using `kill -9 pid` [SIGKILL]
the docker container continues to run.
How can i terminate the docker container when bash script is killed?

I tried using trap but SIGKILL signal can't be trapped so i am trying to find if there are any alternate ways to stop the container

Comment: This isn't specific to Docker. Any time you `kill -9` a script its children will be left orphaned. You would have the same outcome if you ran `sleep` directly in the script: the `bash` process would die and `/usr/bin/sleep` would persist. Lesson: don't use `kill -9` and expect graceful cleanup.

Comment: Why are you using `kill -9`? You're better off doing just `kill` for a SIGTERM, which can be trapped.

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino agent i use to run scripts and terminate sends the SIGKILL signal to terminate the scripts , unfortunately there isn't a way to configure the signal.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can stop your docker container.

```
docker run ubuntu sleep 3000
```

will create a docker image an launch it in a container.

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                     COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS                            PORTS     NAMES
59ba158952c9   ubuntu                                                                    "sleep 3000"   4 seconds ago    Up 3 seconds                                infallible_jackson
34fbe4742f34   ubuntu                                                                    "sleep 1000"   40 seconds ago   Exited (137) 17 seconds ago                 confident_perlman
80a4d44a23be   ubuntu                                                                    "sleep 1000"   2 minutes ago    Exited (137) About a minute ago             busy_colden
e40b91d7b13f   ubuntu                                                                    "sleep 100"    4 minutes ago    Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                    trusting_merkle
```

then you can docker stop 59ba158952c9 (id of the container you want to stop).
and the remove it if necessary

```
docker rm 59ba158952c9
```

I suggest you to have a look at the following documentations:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_rm/

Sorry my answer was not full complete.

let's add the docker command in a script

```
echo "docker run ubuntu sleep 3000" > toto.sh
```

then kill -9 the script:
ps -aux | grep toto

```
mytoto+ 1320784  0.0  0.0  12664  3288 pts/15   S+   07:49   0:00 bash toto.sh
```

then the docker container is still active and you and retrieve it with a grep for instance:

```
docker ps | grep "ubuntu.*sleep 3000" | cut -d" " -f1
2baf9fb7223d
```

copy the id in the variable ID

```
 ID=$(docker ps | grep "ubuntu.*sleep 3000" | cut -d" " -f1)
 echo $ID
    2baf9fb7223d
```

And finally stop / remove the container

```
docker container stop "${ID}"
docker container rm "${ID}"
```

Comment: How do you do that when the script is killed with `kill -9`? That's the question.

Comment: Sorry, the description was not clear to me: it is said: How can i terminate the docker container when bash script is killed? so from what I understood, ramu wanted to stop the container outside the script.
comment edited accordingly.